# Session start problems after upgrading my hosting plan

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-variables, session-state

I just upgraded my hosting plan, and now the user session isnt' working anymore. Users can't access the mebership area when they login, and here are the errors that are shown when opening my website:

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/home/content/15/9277415/tmp/sess_enersdnbm88g5detjemgnptu47, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /home/content/15/9277415/html/include/config.php on line 14
>
> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/15/9277415/html/include/config.php:14) in /home/content/15/9277415/html/include/config.php on line 14
>
> Warning: Unknown: open(/home/content/15/9277415/tmp/sess_enersdnbm88g5detjemgnptu47, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in Unknown on line
>
> Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct () in Unknown on line 0

In config.php line 14 we have the session variables:

```
       if(!session_id()) session_start();
       if (!isset($_SESSION)) $_SESSION=array();
```

Does anybody have any idea why is this happening or how to fix it? These errors werent showing before the hosting plan upgrade.

Comment: Contact your host, it looks like there's an issue with your session settings.

Comment: I think aynber is probably right - assuming you're not overriding the session path (using `session_save_path()` or something) it looks like a configuration error on the server.

Comment: so do you think its not a problem in my website's code, but rather in the hosting company?

Comment: It's a problem of incompatability. You can fix it by changing your code; your hosting provider can fix it by changing his configuration.

Comment: what can I do to fix it by changing my code, because the GoDaddy Costumer Support isn't that nice... what should I replace? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the directory `/home/content/15/9277415/tmp` exists and is writable by the webserver.

Comment: It didn't existed, but I have created one and set the folder permissions to 777, but the same errors appear. Is it possible that if I change the Hosting provider the errors will disapear? (I'm hosting with godaddy right now)